# Why doesn't it print?

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit'] 

letterlist = [ ]
>>> print ( [letterlist.append(letter) for word in wordlist for letter in word if letter not in letterlist])
```

---

This is the output:

```
>>> [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Why doesn't it print out:

```
>>> ['c', 'a', 't', 'd', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'b', 'i']
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the append method returns `None`. It only modifies the list in question.
This will work:

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']

letterlist = [ ]

for word in wordlist:
  for letter in word:
    if letter not in letterlist:
      letterlist.append(letter)

print(letterlist)
```

Comment: the nice thing is that if the alphabet size is finite e.g., 26 letters then `letter not in letterlist` operation is O(1) (constant time).

Answer (score 0):

change program to:

```
wordlist = ['cat','dog','rabbit']
letterlist = []
letterlist = [letter for word in wordlist for letter in word if letter not in letterlist]
print (letterlist)
```

Explanation:

Here you might notice that there is no need for calling an `append` ourself. The `list-comprehension` process itself returns a list, by appending implicitly.

I have separated the `list-comprehansion` and `print` statement for more clarity.

Read more about list comprehension to use it in future applications. It will

1. save you time
2. reduce line of code
3. help you understand what other people's code is doing

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is incorrect. OP wants to create a list without duplicates preserving the order. In your case `letterlist` is empty until the whole new list is created. [@hfhc2 shows the correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28502864/4279)

Comment: here's code that uses listcomp (not recommended): `[letter for word in wordlist for letter in word if letter not in letterlist and not letterlist.append(letter)]`